# How to select where multiple rows have the same values in two columns, respectively?

Tags: sql

For example, from the following table I would want to get back Teams 2 and 4 because they have multiple players with the same name.

```
--Team-- | --Player--
   1     |    John
   1     |    Billy
   2     |    Dillan
   2     |    Brady
   2     |    Brady
   3     |    John
   4     |    Gary
   4     |    Gary
```

Comment: GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the team names (and not the names of the duplicate players), then one method is to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Team
FROM TeamPlayer
GROUP BY Team, Player
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I mention that because `SELECT DISTINCT` in an aggregation query is almost always a mistake, but this is one valid use.

That said, I would might be more inclined to do:

```
SELECT Team
FROM TeamPlayer
GROUP BY Team
HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(DISTINCT Player);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` + `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Team,  Player
FROM dbo.TeamPlayer
GROUP BY Team, Player
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/110ff/1/0)</kbd>